# Website, app or book with verbs used in sentences

Tags: usage, verbes, ressources

I am brushing up on what little French I learned when I used to take classes two years ago and I'm looking for a reference where I can look up verbs and find plenty - no, LOTS - of examples where the verbs are used in sentences. My book 501 French Verbs provides only three sentences per verb. I have other grammar textbooks where each new verb being introduced is only used once or twice. Any suggestions? Books and searchable websites will also do.

Comment: internet ? google or search-engines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/)? It allows to search for a word and show different samples containing that word.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for!